# Hide email in Stripe Checkout

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments, stripe-connect

How to disable or hide email in checkout.js in Stripe Payment

```
onStripeUpdate(e) {
    this.stripehandler.open({
      name: "",
      description: "",
      panelLabel: "Pay {{amount}}",
      allowRememberMe: false,
      email: "", //--->how to hide this email?
    });
    e.preventDefault();
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not possible to disable the email field entirely. You can pass a value for the `email` [configuration option](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#optional), but it must be a valid email address. If it's a valid address, the field will be replaced by a static label with the value you provided.

If you don't provide the `email` option, or if you provide an invalid value (such as an empty string in your example code), then the email field will still be displayed.